# Storage Spaces Direct

Tags: storage, windows-server-2016, azure-pack

Some background:
I'm trying to set up Azure Pack in a test environment, and are currently woriking on setting up the servers who's going to host it all.

To do this i have two virtual Windows Server 2016 TP4 servers hostet on a ESXI host, and so i need to set up Storage Spaces Direct.
(iSCSI target and Storage Spaces (WS 2012), have been ruled out since the first is a nightmare to set up and the internet told me the second one comes with a low R/W speed).

I've been following this guide: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt126109.aspx

Problem:
When i run this cmdlet: Enable-ClusterStorageSpacesDirect
, I get this warning: No elegible DAS disk found.

Both servers have 3 disk each. They are initialized and 100% unallocated, and I have tried with them beeing both offline and online.

If I try running this cmdlet: (Get-Cluster).DasModeEnabled=1
I get the following error: The property 'DasModeEnabled' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Any and all help is greatly appriciated!

Comment: Hey guys, 
I am facing similar issue. I have run Enable-ClusterS2D first and have seen this: http://imgur.com/2FjrYEX
I think I am missing smth too. I am trying to build S2D for testing in my VMware test lab.

Answer (score 3):

Storage Spaces Direct doesn't support FC & RAID-controlled LUNs. 
The key is to force S2D to accept RAID BusType:

```
(Get-Cluster).S2DBusTypes=256
```

Here's a good article about it https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/resolving-enable-clusters2d-bus-type-support-issue-on-some-storage-controllers.
Another option is to reflash the controller's firmware to IT mode.

There's also other solutions, like that Starwind, which I suggest you to test.